# Issue tracking multiple domains with Google Analytics

Tags: domains, google-analytics, analytics, tracking, multiple-domains

I have 2 domains `mydomain.com` and `mydomain.net` which I'm trying to track with the same `GA` code. Here are the options I turned on:

```
Subdomains of mydomain   ON
Examples: www.mydomain.com -and- apps.mydomain.com -and- store.mydomain.com

Multiple top-level domains of mydomain  ON
Examples: mydomain.uk -and- mydomain.cn -and- mydomain.fr
```

Which gave me the following code:

```
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-123456789-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

[In this help page](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034342&topic=2772342&ctx=topic) I read that `_setDomainName` must be changed for each domain
which I did:
-if you go to `mydomain.net` you get `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.net']);`
-if you go to `mydomain.com` you get `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.com']);`

When I generate traffic on both `mydomain.dom` and `mydomain.net` and watches `GA` push requests made with `firebug` I can see requests generated for both domains and the parameter called `utmhn` has the proper domain value (which matches that of `_setDomainName` and the browser address bar).

However when I monitor the realtime statistics under `Home->Real-Time->Overview` I see `pageviews` for `mydomain.net` **BUT NOT** for `mydomain.dom` :(

**What am I missing to properly track both domains?**

*PS: [in the help page I mentioned](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034342&topic=2772342&ctx=topic) they talk about setting up `cross links` which I didn't do for now as my understanding is that it shouldn't be needed to get what I'm trying to do to work. Also I want to mention that I do not have any tracking code for any of these 2 domains other than the one I mentioned.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question I mentioned that I didn't have any other tracking codes for the domains which was true but the tracking codes had been removed recently so maybe this was what was causing the issue. Anyway what I did was:
-removed all the tracking codes
-waited 30 min
-created a new tracking code

Now everything is working fine.